# can more than one aggregation functions be used in `select` in case of `group by`?

Tags: mysql, sql

here is the table:

[image]

here is my query

```
select sum(if(customer_pref_delivery_date = min(order_date), 1, 0)) immidiate_percentage
from Delivery
group by customer_id;
```

then I get error

```
Invalid use of group function
```

Ignore what I want to do logically, I'm wondering why I get this error? when I remove `sum` from the `select` it works, so I'm thinking maybe in `sql` only one aggregation function (like `min` in this case) be allowed to use in `select` when doing `group by`? is that true?

Comment: Yes it is true. You can't nest aggregations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't nest aggregations in the select list.
If you want to get the percentage of the orders that need to be delivered at the same day as the order per customer then do this:

```
select customer_id, 
  100.0 * avg(customer_pref_delivery_date = order_date) immediate_percentage
from Delivery
group by customer_id;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cxsz4YtJZ8qpxZLLo9fYSi/0).
Results:

```
| customer_id | immediate_percentage |
| ----------- | -------------------- |
| 1           | 0                    |
| 2           | 50                   |
| 3           | 50                   |
| 4           | 100                  |
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot nest aggregation functions.  It simply doesn't make sense.  Each aggregation function produces one value per group -- the value cannot then be compared to the rows that comprise the group in the same `select`.

I don't think you need any second aggregation for what you are doing:

```
select customer_id, sum( customer_pref_delivery_date = order_date ) as immediate_percentage
from (select d.*,
             min(order_date) over (partition by customer_id) as min_order_date
      from Delivery
     ) d
group by customer_id;
```

It seems strange that you are calling a sum a "percentage" but that is the logic you have in your query.

If you really want to compare to the minimum order date for each customer, you can use a window function:

```
select customer_id, sum( customer_pref_delivery_date = min_order_date ) as immediate_percentage
from (select d.*,
             min(order_date) over (partition by customer_id) as min_order_date
      from Delivery
     ) d
group by customer_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot nest aggregate functions.

One way to work around this would to compute the minimum order date per customer in a subquery, and then join it with the original table, as follows:

```
select 
    d.customer_id
    sum(if(d.customer_pref_delivery_date = dmin.min_order_date), 1, 0)) immidiate_percentage
from 
    delivery d
    inner join (
        select customer_id, min(order_date) min_order_date
        from delivery
        group by customer_id
    ) dmin on dmin.customer_id = d.customer_id
group by d.customer_id;
```

In MySQL 8.0, you can use window functions:

```
select
    d.customer_id,
    sum(if(customer_pref_delivery_date = min_order_date), 1, 0)) immidiate_percentage   
from (
    select 
        customer_id, 
        customer_pref_delivery_date,
        min(order_date) over(partition by customer_id) min_order_date
    from delivery
) t
group by customer_id
```